# Updating created users in CloudFormation template resets their passwords

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am creating a CloudFormation template that will have users.
The user I created has a password and should be changed first time he logs in.
My issue is that whenever I update the CF template, let's say I created a new user then the old users passwords will get reset which is unacceptable for me.
This is my code

```
JohnDoeUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
        Groups: 
            - !Ref DevelopersGroup
        LoginProfile: 
            Password: "Pa$$wOrd123456!#"
            PasswordResetRequired: true
        ManagedPolicyArns: 
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
```

(Trying to avoid SSO)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating created users CloudFormation template resets their passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77482236/updating-created-users-cloudformation-template-resets-their-passwords)

Comment: @kichik That question is a duplicate, and it's not even answered.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBoudreau. That is an automated comment I didn't write. It's the result of flagging the question for closing as it's duplicated.

Comment: @kichik Gotcha, good to know!

Comment: There's no native way to prevent this from happening as what you want is intended stack drift. Much better to use a script (boto3 etc..) to prevision users for this reason. If you really want to use cloudformation for this you could add a deletion policy of retain on the resource and immediately run a stack update on the stack with the desired resources removed from the cfn template. This is awful in practice and I'd recommend just writing as script.

Comment: @Kisaragi can terraform help avoid this issue?